# php - grammar - new Activation\Activate

Tags: php, class, oop

Can someone explain how this line of PHP works:

```
new Activation\Activate;
```

I can see an Activation/Activate.php file.

Is the backslash a new PHP construct or does it simply mean to load the `Activation/Activate.php` file but is confusing me 'cos I'm on a Mac (i.e. I'm expecting a forward slash)?

Comment: It's just a simple instanciation of a class. And the `\ `  is just a namespace -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means using a namespace

More about PHP namespaces:
https://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php